# How can I select option value using a value which is url in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select option based on a value. In my case, I have options as value. For example:

```
<form>
    <select name="floc" id="floc">
                <option value="0">Select Locations</option>
                <option value="https://austin.partyprincessproductions.com/">Austin, TEXAS</option>
                <option value="https://boston.partyprincessproductions.com/">Boston, MASSACHUSETTS</option>
                <option value="https://chicago.partyprincessproductions.com/">Chicago, ILLINOIS</option>
    </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#floc').val("https://austin.partyprincessproductions.com");
</script>
```

This is not working. But When I replece it with simple value, it's working, like

```
<form>
    <select name="floc" id="floc">
                <option value="0">Select Locations</option>
                <option value="apple">Austin, TEXAS</option>
                <option value="bananna">Boston, MASSACHUSETTS</option>
                <option value="mango">Chicago, ILLINOIS</option>
    </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#floc').val("apple");
</script>
```

This code is working perfect and it is selecting Austin. But I have to work with url as option, how I can deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the forward slash `/` at the end of the value when you are setting it using the Jquery.

```
$('#floc').val("https://austin.partyprincessproductions.com");
```

should be

```
$('#floc').val("https://austin.partyprincessproductions.com/");
```

```js
  $('#floc').val("https://austin.partyprincessproductions.com/");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select name="floc" id="floc">
                <option value="0">Select Locations</option>
                <option value="https://austin.partyprincessproductions.com/">Austin, TEXAS</option>
                <option value="https://boston.partyprincessproductions.com/">Boston, MASSACHUSETTS</option>
                <option value="https://chicago.partyprincessproductions.com/">Chicago, ILLINOIS</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Or if you do not want the last forward slash remove them from all `value` attribute of the `option`.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks. Actually I was getting value through a function get_site_url() and I was missing to add / after that.